# How to change $routeParams parameters?

Tags: routes, angularjs

Im accessing this url: http://bazarak.af/#!/annonser/page=1&...

```
.when("/annonser/:query",{
    templateUrl: '/views/search.php',
    controller: "Search"
})
```

I would like to get the value of page and change it both in the url and in the routeParams.

To get the page value I have tried

```
var pageNumber = $routeParams.page;
```

and to set it I have tried:

```
$routeParams ==> {page:5}
```

None of this works. And the documentation is not really helping me.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use $location.path() to set new URL path. It will be reflected in routes as well. 
You can also just change $location.search to change your query
Read this documentation 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Documentation now at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location. Also, `$location.search()` can be used to change just parameters.

Answer (score 11):

Using `$location.path()` requires that you can give it the hole path including search params and hash so you would need to parse the url in order to change a single parameter in the middle of the url such as this one `/user/:id/inbox/:read` then its easier to use:

```
// given the current url is http://example.com/user/3/inbox/unread?sort=desc
$route.updateParams({id:"2"});
// will become http://example.com/user/2/inbox/unread?sort=desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following to clear all the route parameters from the url:

```
var myParams = new Object();
for(var param in $routeParams){
 myParams[param] = null;
}
$route.updateParams(myParams);
```