# AngularJs Change url generated using index of and routeparams

Tags: angularjs

In the address bar of the browser the $routeProvider returns ".../index#/projects/0".
This is the view for that particular project. What I am trying to achieve is to  either hide the indexOf value, in this case the "0" and have the url as ".../index#/projects/somethingelse". Linking to the project using `<a href="#/projects/{{projects.indexOf(project)}}">` and "/projects/:id" in the $routeProvider config. I have tried certain methods but cannot get any results.

Say for example the the first project in the projects array is called, the url in the browser is "/projects/0". Is it possible to replace the 0 to have the url start at 1 but still return the values of the object in project array[0] and so on. Basically trying to find a rewrite method in the controller or service. Currently grasping AngularJS.

I have come accross this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166787/how-to-change-routeparams-parameters) but don't know how to go about doing this to achieve what I need. Going by this answer I tried the following code in the controller `$location.path($route.updateParams({id:"project"}));` it does give the desired result: from ".../index#/projects/0" to "../index#/projects/project" but when navigated to the view, it is blank and the project details are not returned.

Also any good pointers, tutorials, books on URL rewrites and security in AngularJS? The AngularJs version I am using is 1.5.8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want in the route params, so long as you can link it to the right data.

If you want to offset the index by 1, simply use something like this (assuming `projects` is available / injectable)

```
.when('/projects/:id', {
    resolve: {
        project: function($routeParams, projects) {
            return projects[$routeParams.id - 1];
        }
    },
    // etc
```

To use an arbitrary property like `id`, try [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
resolve: {
    project: function($routeParams, projects) {
        return projects.find(project => project.id === $routeParams.id);
    }
}
```

---

To create links, you'd use something like

```
<a ng-href="#/projects/{{projects.indexOf(project) + 1}}">
```

or

```
<a ng-href="#/projects/{{project.id}}">
```

Comment: the offset works but the <a> of the first project in the array still points to 0 on the live application. so basically when i click on this project the url will still navigate to /projects/0 but no data returned When i navigate to /projects/1 the data of that project: projects[0] is then returned thats as a result of the offset. Need to prevent /project/0 in the url. Can iI send you a link to the repository and see what I mean? @Phil

Comment: @Chief How are you creating the `<a>` tag? It's really just up to you as to how the URLs are created

Comment: <a ng-href="#/projects/{{projects.indexOf(project)}}"> was the initial, I have to admit earlier I did make an error when changing the link from <a ng-href="#/projects/{{projects.indexOf(project)}}"> to <a ng-href="#/projects/{{projects.indexOf(project) + 1}}"> so it matches the offset. 1. I realised now that i was editing in the wrong view. 2. I was adding the 1 inside of indexOf which always returned -1. 3. I was really  tired to realise indexOf -1 = no match found.  School boy errors,  I appreciate the feedback. it has helped me learn something new. @Phil